# R igraph curved edges

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I would like to plot some star graphs in R. But, if I plot (large) full graphs, for example K_5, than there goes an edge from one node to another node through the center node. You can see that in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJuYU.png) (sry I'm new here, therefore I think, I can't upload images directly).
Now, if I curve all edges, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RORuG.png). But this looks like also a bit ugly. I want only curve the edges {2,4} and {3,5}. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Sry, "full graph" was only an example to get a class of problematic graphs. You can plot this as follows:

```
adj <- matrix(1,5,5)  
adj[1,1] <- 0   
adj[2,2] <- 0   
adj[3,3] <- 0   
adj[4,4] <- 0   
adj[5,5] <- 0  

g = graph.adjacency(adj, mode="undirected",diag=FALSE)  
plot(g, layout=layout.star, vertex.label.color= "black")
```

Comment: How are you getting that layout? Because `plot(make_full_graph(5))` gets me the nodes on a pentagon, not a square with a centre node...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, to curve the edges between vertices 4&5 and 3&1, you could to:

```
library(igraph)
make_full_graph(5) %>%
  set_edge_attr("curved", value=0) %>%
  set_edge_attr("curved", E(.)[4%--%5,3%--%1], .2) %>%
  plot
```

See ["Indexing edge sequences"](http://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph-es-indexing.html)

Comment: Great, that's what I want. Thank you very much. :)